# Table empty in hive because of a CASE

Tags: sql, hiveql

I've recently started to learn sql and I've got no prior coding experince, so it may only be one stupid mistake (in that case, sorry for the long post :) ). It' be great if you could help me with my current issue.

I've got a table that looks like this

id/n (the name of the particular event)/ utc (the timestamp)/json_data (a json strings including several parameters).

My goal is simple: I'm trying to get the sum, grouped by n, of the value parameters found in json_data. Unfortunately, some issues make the execution a little more complicated.

1. We have a spamming issue, that cause identical events to be sent hundreds or thousands of times, and they need to be filtered out. I typically solve it by using utc (the timestamp) in a group clause that will also include the other selected columns, and get one instance of each particular event.
2. Some events return negative values in their "value field", and these need to be ignored from all the counting and summing.
3. Since things can't ever be easy, the name of the value field in the json_data column is always different, depending on the type of event that is sent. However, I got this pretty much sorted out with the various string manipulations you can see in my query.

Here's what I got so far

```
SELECT
b.Event_Name as Event_Name
, COUNT(b.Event_Name) as event_occurrences
, SUM(b.item_value) as user_spendings
FROM
    (SELECT
        a.id as Player_ID
        , a.n as Event_Name
        , a.utc as timing
        , CASE 
            WHEN 
                MAX( a.ALPHA_Value
                + a.BETA_Value
                + a.GAMMA_Value
                + a.DELTA_Value
                + a.EPSILON_Value
                + a.BETAUPGRADE_Value
                + a.ZETA_Value
                + a.ALPHASKIN_Value
                + a.UPGRADEALPHA_Value) <= 0 
            THEN 0 
            ELSE 
                MAX(a.ALPHA_Value
                + a.BETA_Value
                + a.GAMMA_Value
                + a.DELTA_Value
                + a.EPSILON_Value
                + a.BETAUPGRADE_Value
                + a.ZETA_Value
                + a.ALPHASKIN_Value
                + a.UPGRADEALPHA_Value) END as item_value
        FROM
            (SELECT
                id
                , n
                , utc
                , MAX(TRIM(get_json_object(json_data, '$. ALPHA_Value '))) as ALPHA_Value
                , MAX(TRIM(get_json_object(json_data, '$. BETA_Value '))) as BETA_Value
                , MAX(SUBSTR
                    (TRIM(get_json_object(json_data, '$. GAMMA_Value ')), 6, 
                        (LOCATE(' resource 2', 
                            SUBSTR
                                (TRIM(get_json_object(json_data, '$. GAMMA_Value ')), 6))-1))) as GAMMA_Value
                , MAX(SUBSTR
                    (TRIM(get_json_object(json_data, '$. DELTA_Value ')), 6)) as DELTA_Value
                , MAX(SUBSTR
                    (TRIM(get_json_object(json_data, '$. EPSILON_Value ')), 6)) as EPSILON_Value
                , MAX(SUBSTR
                    (TRIM(get_json_object(json_data, '$. BETAUPGRADE_Value ')), 6)) as BETAUPGRADE_Value
                , MAX(SUBSTR
                    (TRIM(get_json_object(json_data, '$. ZETA_Value ')), 6)) as ZETA_Value
                , MAX(SUBSTR
                    (TRIM(get_json_object(json_data, '$. ALPHASKIN_Value ')), 6)) as ALPHASKIN_Value
                , MAX(SUBSTR
                    (TRIM(get_json_object(json_data, '$. UPGRADEALPHA_Value ')), 6, 
                        (LOCATE(' resource 2', 
                            SUBSTR
                                (TRIM(get_json_object(json_data, '$. UPGRADEALPHA_Value ')), 6))-1))) as UPGRADEALPHA_Value
                FROM application_events
                WHERE
                    month = 201409
                    AND FROM_UNIXTIME(utc_timestamp) > '2014-09-04 12:00:00'
                GROUP BY id, n, utc
                ORDER BY id, n
            ) a
        GROUP by a.id, a.n, a.utc
        ORDER by timing, Event_Name
    ) b
WHERE b.item_value > 0
GROUP by b.Event_Name
ORDER by user_spendings
```

My reasoning is as follows:

1. I get the values out of json_data while getting rid of the spam with GROUP by id, n, utc. I use MAX on get_json_object to allow the grouping with the previous columns. Since the combinations of id, name, and timestamp are unique (except for the spam ofc), the MAX will work on identical values.
   Since every event has only 1 value field (with varying names based on the event type), i'll have all columns, but only one will have a value (the others will be empty).

   2. I get rid of negative values: right now, since i was not able to put a sum in the where clause, the only way i could think of was to create another table (b) which will check if the sum of all value columns from a is negative (as i said, they'll all be empty except for one, so if there's a negative, the sum will be too), and return the sum if it is not (aliased as item_value).
   3. The third table will finally count the number of events and sum the values.

My current issue is at step 2. When I run the Subquery a, it looks fine, I get results. When I run a inside the original query (the one counting the events and summing the value), I get results too. So I guess theres something wrong with the way i put the condition, because the full query gives me no results in the table.

I tried putting the sum in the WHERE clause, didn't work. Any ideas are welcome, especially if you know easier ways of doing this.

Thank you very much guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks correct, I removed some extra parts (but it's not essesntial):

```
SELECT
b.Event_Name as Event_Name
, COUNT(b.Event_Name) as event_occurrences
, SUM(b.item_value) as user_spendings
FROM (SELECT
        a.id as Player_ID
        , a.n as Event_Name
        , a.utc as timing
          COALESCE(a.ALPHA_Value, CAST(0 AS BIGINT))
        + COALESCE(a.BETA_Value, CAST(0 AS BIGINT))
        + COALESCE(a.GAMMA_Value, CAST(0 AS BIGINT))
        + COALESCE(a.DELTA_Value, CAST(0 AS BIGINT))
        + COALESCE(a.EPSILON_Value, CAST(0 AS BIGINT))
        + COALESCE(a.BETAUPGRADE_Value, CAST(0 AS BIGINT))
        + COALESCE(a.ZETA_Value, CAST(0 AS BIGINT))
        + COALESCE(a.ALPHASKIN_Value, CAST(0 AS BIGINT))
        + COALESCE(a.UPGRADEALPHA_Value, CAST(0 AS BIGINT)) as item_value
        FROM (SELECT
                id
                , n
                , utc
                , MAX(TRIM(get_json_object(json_data, '$. ALPHA_Value '))) as ALPHA_Value
                , MAX(TRIM(get_json_object(json_data, '$. BETA_Value '))) as BETA_Value
                , MAX(SUBSTR
                    (TRIM(get_json_object(json_data, '$. GAMMA_Value ')), 6, 
                        (LOCATE(' resource 2', 
                            SUBSTR
                                (TRIM(get_json_object(json_data, '$. GAMMA_Value ')), 6))-1))) as GAMMA_Value
                , MAX(SUBSTR
                    (TRIM(get_json_object(json_data, '$. DELTA_Value ')), 6)) as DELTA_Value
                , MAX(SUBSTR
                    (TRIM(get_json_object(json_data, '$. EPSILON_Value ')), 6)) as EPSILON_Value
                , MAX(SUBSTR
                    (TRIM(get_json_object(json_data, '$. BETAUPGRADE_Value ')), 6)) as BETAUPGRADE_Value
                , MAX(SUBSTR
                    (TRIM(get_json_object(json_data, '$. ZETA_Value ')), 6)) as ZETA_Value
                , MAX(SUBSTR
                    (TRIM(get_json_object(json_data, '$. ALPHASKIN_Value ')), 6)) as ALPHASKIN_Value
                , MAX(SUBSTR
                    (TRIM(get_json_object(json_data, '$. UPGRADEALPHA_Value ')), 6, 
                        (LOCATE(' resource 2', 
                            SUBSTR
                                (TRIM(get_json_object(json_data, '$. UPGRADEALPHA_Value ')), 6))-1))) as UPGRADEALPHA_Value
                FROM application_events
                WHERE
                    month = 201409
                    AND FROM_UNIXTIME(utc_timestamp) > '2014-09-04 12:00:00'
                GROUP BY id, n, utc
            ) a
    ) b
WHERE b.item_value > 0
GROUP by b.Event_Name
ORDER by user_spendings
```

I suppose some values you are trying to sum are NULL. So I added COALESCE

P.S. you don't need subquery "b", you may do the same in the subquery "a", but I did't touch this for better readability

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna run it.

Empty columns return /N, summing this with a numerical value is what makes the query return an empty table you think?

Comment: @QuiZzer Yes, I think so